# Application process gets bigger even with using statements

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, memory-leaks

Is seems like I have a memory leak because I see the process is getting bigger each minute.

Please assist :-)

```
while (true)
{
    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
    {
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            try
            {
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
                bitmap.Save(@path + System.Environment.MachineName + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
            catch (Exception) // Handle file save problems
            {
                if (File.Exists("path.save"))
                {
                    File.Delete("path.save");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Thread.Sleep(15000);
}
```

Comment: GC runs in-deterministically. It will free the memory once it runs. Are you sure memory never gets released? Does application crashes with Out Of Memory exception?

Comment: Why are you using Thread.Sleep? That is bad practice. Secondly, why is it doing the same thing again and again in a while loop? Whilst the using block will dispose of the object in question, as said earlier the GC will run when it needs to run and will clean up the objects when it needs to. It could also be that you are holding on to a reference somewhere else causing it to not clean up but still linger around

Comment: @RohitVats, thanks for the input, it look like it gets bigger (started at 4,000K and not the process is 7,000K, after an hour).
I'm not sure how much time should I wait for the release...

Comment: @Ahmedilyas, why is it bad practice ? I've tried using timer but the process became 145,000K (not sure why).
The original code had the bmp outside of the loop (caused it to be 12,000K) and after I used the using statement it became 4,000K so I figured it might be a good idea to use it and dispose in the loop.
The main idea is to capture the screen every 15 seconds and overwrite the previous screenshot file.

Comment: How are you measuring memory?

Comment: `using` blocks have nothing to do with memory usage. Also, dude, it's _virtual_ memory, and measuring it via Task Manager is not an accurate measure. If you leave the application running, is there eventually an `OutOfMemoryException`?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, thanks for the input.
This is my first C# application so I'm kinda new to how to measure memory issues (I do 'use' Task Manager).
The application is running with no OutOfMemExceptions.

Comment: You may have a problem with large object heap fragmentation. Read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2011/10/04/large-object-heap-improvements-in-net-4-5.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I constantly keep telling people why thread.sleep is bad practice so.. thanks to Peter Ritchie, most of my views are shared with him but there is so much more than the basic list here: http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2009/06/24/880146.aspx

Comment: So, my suggestion is to ignore Task Manager. Worry if you're getting OutOfMemory (OOM) exceptions, or if there is a lot of paging. Otherwise, the Task Manager number is a number without much meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running the process for 24 hours, I saw that the memory column was stable after a couple of hours, and as most of you people said, I should never worry about this column again :-)
Thanks for the tips, I know much more now !